# Как подключить USB библиотеку к stm32?

Tags: usb, stm32

Пытался найти библиотеку для stm32L152, для этого микроконтроллера библиотеку не вижу,
есть для stm32f103 внутри решений, а не отдельно.

С чего начать работу c USB? Нет ли библиотеки USB одним куском, как вообще подключить библиотеку USB с чего начинать? Интерисует USB-HID.

Как я понял вопрос делится на несколько частей. Первая - выставить тактирование. Вначале нужно правильно выставить тактирование. Второе - просто заполнить дескриптор и активировать USB. И третье - как организованы каллбеки-USB.

Пробовал смотреть чужие проэкты, там примерно штук 2 по 10 файлов USB_*.c и USB_*.h соответственно, они между собой связаны, сложно понять что там и к чему.

Пробовал создать проэкт через CubeMX - его не знаю как импортировать в emblocks.

Кто сталкивался с проблемой в освоении USB, что лучше почитать и как вы решили проблему с USB?

Comment: А почему нужно именно emblocks? Здесь CubeMX - самый быстрый способ решить задачу.

Comment: Если в emblocks компилятор на основе GCC, то можно в CubeMX выбрать TrueStudio.

Comment: @maestro Emblocks бесплатный, и под ним получилось собрать проэкт, и собрать примеры с хабра. Не помогло TrueStudio, учитывая ситуацию... попробую ещё раз разные среды перебрать и попробую собрать "минимальный проэкт". Cocox сейчас пробую... его вроде хвалили...

Comment: почему бы вам просто не использовать CubeIDE?

Comment: @haze он то ли платный, не удалось найти ссылку с cubeIDE c бесплатным скачиванием

Comment: Для линукса он есть на flathub